# Codeception Unable to find executable for: taskkill

Tags: php, selenium, webdriver, codeception, taskkill

I'm currently doing Codeception acceptance tests and ran into the **Error:**

> [Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownServerException] Unable to find
>   executable for: taskkill

The rest of the Code is working perfectly fine. It opens the Browser (Firefox) and it closes it after the tests are done, but I still get this error.

Google told me to add `C:\Windows\system32` to the PATH, which I did, but I'm still getting the Error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be that it cannot find 'taskkill' on **the machine running the tests** (what selenium calls 'nodes' in a selenium grid setup).

Make sure that taskkill is installed on the node and that their PATH environment variable contains `C:\Windows\system32`

References/Useful links:

- [PATH Environment Variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))
- [This same issue listed in GitHub](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/2362)